# How to change color of this header tag?

Tags: xml, xslt, colors, xsl-fo

I’m editing an .xsl for an XML pdf output, and we are trying to change the color of the header throughout. Right now, the header is a xsl:template name=“header-main” which is referenced in many places.
Would I enter the color tag in the “fo:table” tag? Or would I just simply do a fo:background color tag? Basically how do I do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Can you add a screenshot of an existing header with an indication of what you want to change and/or a copy of your `xsl:template` (at least from `<xsl:template...` down to the `fo:table` element that you think you want to change)?

Comment: Hi @AllexKramer. Please check out how to create a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is a Minimal Reproducible Example, and edit your question. That will make it easier to help you.